# Setting ylim in R's plot.lm residual plot

Tags: r, plot

Let's say I'm doing a linear model with `y ~ x`. I get the residuals plot for example with

```
plot(lm(y ~ x, data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,6,9))), 1)
```

How can I set the ylim for this plot? (Supplying e.g. ylim=c(-1,1) to this function doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ylim` is hard-coded into the function `stats:::plot.lm` (i.e., the s3 `plot` method for objects of class "lm"). This function is not exported from the stats package. To get around this, you could copy the function and modify it:

```
plotlm <- stats:::plot.lm
```

You can edit it using `fix("plotlm")`. Add a `ylim` formal argument to the function definition and then find the relevant part of the code. You should change:

```
if (show[1L]) {
    ylim <- range(r, na.rm = TRUE)
    if (id.n > 0) 
        ylim <- extendrange(r = ylim, f = 0.08)
    dev.hold()
    plot(yh, r, xlab = l.fit, ylab = "Residuals", main = main, 
        ylim = ylim, type = "n", ...)
# ...
```

to:

```
if (show[1L]) {
    if(missing(ylim)) {
        ylim <- range(r, na.rm = TRUE)
        if (id.n > 0) 
            ylim <- extendrange(r = ylim, f = 0.08)
    }
    dev.hold()
    plot(yh, r, xlab = l.fit, ylab = "Residuals", main = main, 
        ylim = ylim, type = "n", ...)
# ...
```

Then you can call this new function:

```
plotlm(lm(y ~ x, data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,6,9))), 1, ylim = c(-1,1))
```

And obtain the desired result:

[image]